# Identityserver4 and Redis cache not thread safe?

Tags: identityserver4, stackexchange.redis

We use IdentityServer4 to protect our ASPnetCore API's on Azure. This afternoon we were challenged with a very strange occurrence.

One of our API's simply returns all items from a database table based on the sub claim of our user (e.g. userid). Today two users reported seeing not their own items. This code has been running flawless for some years now.

Our startup.cs contains the following:

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(action =>
            {
                action.Configuration = Configuration["RedisConnectionString"];
            });

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration["identityServerUrl"];
                    options.ApiName = "<<redacted>>";
                    options.ApiSecret = "<<redacted>>";
                    options.EnableCaching = true;
                    options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                });
```

Because of timeout issues on Redis, we added the following line:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(300, 300);
```

Could this have anything to do with userid's being swapped?
As it is a protected API, all requests have a bearer token which is validated in Redis with the above logic. How could the userid suddenly be different?

Thanks for thinking with me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the call of seeing all wrong data was misinterpreted and the logic mentioned above still works as expected. The userid is correct.
We still have some other issue to work out though, but that is not related to this question.